# Dont get full GPU-Utilization for my GAN implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I build a `GAN` network that predict a output of the shape `(40,40,6)` form two inputs of the shapes `[(40,40,4),(20,20,6)]`.

The model is actually working and already delivers results but I "only" get a GPU utilization between 60 and 70% (displayed by nvidia-smi).

My question is if that is intrinsic for such a model as it has to do stuff in between the calls of `train_on_batch` or if there is way to speed this process up?

A minimalist working example on random data would look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import os


import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import UpSampling3D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Add
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)






# =============================================================================
# define the model    
# =============================================================================

def resBlock(X_in, num_of_features, kernel_size, scale):

    x = Conv2D(num_of_features, kernel_size, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same')(X_in)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(num_of_features, kernel_size, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same')(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: x * scale)(x)

    X_out = Add()([X_in,x])

    return X_out

class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self, noise_shape):

        self.noise_shape = noise_shape
        self.num_of_features = 128
        self.kernel_size = (3,3)
        self.scale = 0.1
        self.padding=8
        self.hp = int(self.padding/2) # half padding

    def generator(self):

        # get the inputs and do upsampling
        inputs_channels_A = Input((32+self.padding,32+self.padding,4),name = 'input_A')
        inputs_channels_B = Input((16+self.hp,16+self.hp,6),name = 'input_B')
        inputs_channels_B_upsampled = UpSampling3D(size = (2,2,1))(inputs_channels_B)

        # concentrate everything
        concentrated_input = concatenate([inputs_channels_A,
                                          inputs_channels_B_upsampled],
                                          axis=3,)

        # do the first convolution
        x = Conv2D(self.num_of_features,
                   self.kernel_size,
                   activation = 'relu',
                   padding = 'same',
                   kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(concentrated_input)

        # do the resBlock iterations
        for resblock_index in range(6):
            x = resBlock(x,self.num_of_features, self.kernel_size, self.scale)

        # doing the last conv to resize it to (28,28,6)
        x = Conv2D(6, (3, 3), kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same')(x)

        # last scipt connection
        output = Add()([x,inputs_channels_B_upsampled])

        # defining model
        generator_model = Model(inputs = [inputs_channels_A,inputs_channels_B], outputs = output)

        return generator_model

def discriminator_block(model, filters, kernel_size, strides):

    model = Conv2D(filters = filters, kernel_size = kernel_size, strides = strides, padding = "same")(model)
    model = BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.5)(model)
    model = LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(model)

    return model

class Discriminator(object):

    def __init__(self, image_shape):

        self.image_shape = image_shape

    def discriminator(self):

        dis_input = Input(shape = (self.image_shape))

        model = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, padding = "same")(dis_input)
        model = LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(model)

        model = discriminator_block(model, 64, 3, 2)
        model = discriminator_block(model, 128, 3, 1)
        model = discriminator_block(model, 128, 3, 2)
        model = discriminator_block(model, 256, 3, 1)
        model = discriminator_block(model, 256, 3, 2)
        model = discriminator_block(model, 512, 3, 1)
        model = discriminator_block(model, 512, 3, 2)

        model = Flatten()(model)
        model = Dense(1024)(model)
        model = LeakyReLU(alpha = 0.2)(model)

        model = Dense(1)(model)
        model = Activation('sigmoid')(model) 

        discriminator_model = Model(inputs = dis_input, outputs = model)

        return discriminator_model   

def get_gan_network(discriminator, shape_list_AB, generator, optimizer, loss):

    discriminator.trainable = False

    gan_input_A = Input(shape=shape_list_AB[0])
    gan_input_B = Input(shape=shape_list_AB[1])

    x = generator([gan_input_A,gan_input_B])
    gan_output = discriminator(x)

    gan = Model(inputs=[gan_input_A,gan_input_B], outputs=[x,gan_output])
    gan.compile(loss=[loss, "binary_crossentropy"], loss_weights=[1., 1e-3], optimizer=optimizer)

    return gan


def get_optimizer():
    adam = Adam(lr=1E-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    return adam





# =============================================================================
# choose some parameters and compile the model
# =============================================================================

batch_size = 128
shape_input_A = (40,40,4)
shape_input_B = (20,20,6)
shape_output = (40,40,6)


generator = Generator(shape_input_B).generator() # todo shape
discriminator = Discriminator(shape_output).discriminator() # todo shape

optimizer = get_optimizer()

generator.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
discriminator.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer)

gan = get_gan_network(discriminator, [shape_input_A,shape_input_B], generator, optimizer, "mse")  




# =============================================================================
# training
# =============================================================================

def get_random_data(mod):

    # get the networks input
    if mod == 0: 
        return [np.random.rand(batch_size,40,40,4),np.random.rand(batch_size,20,20,6)]

    # get the networks output
    else: 
        return np.random.rand(batch_size,40,40,6)


# initalize empty arrays
rand_nums = np.empty(batch_size,dtype=np.int)
image_batch_lr = np.empty((batch_size,)+shape_input_B)
image_batch_hr = np.empty((batch_size,)+shape_output)
generated_images_sr = np.empty_like(image_batch_hr)
real_data_Y = np.empty(batch_size)
fake_data_Y = np.empty(batch_size)

for e in range(1, 10):

    print("epoch:",e)

    for batchindex in range(200):

        generated_images_sr[:] = generator.predict(get_random_data(0))

        real_data_Y[:] = np.ones(batch_size) - np.random.random_sample(batch_size)*0.2
        fake_data_Y[:] = np.random.random_sample(batch_size)*0.2

        discriminator.trainable = True

        d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(get_random_data(1), real_data_Y)
        d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(generated_images_sr, fake_data_Y)
        discriminator_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_fake, d_loss_real)

        gan_Y = np.ones(batch_size) - np.random.random_sample(batch_size)*0.2
        discriminator.trainable = False
        gan_loss = gan.train_on_batch(get_random_data(0), [get_random_data(1),gan_Y])


    print("discriminator_loss : %f" % discriminator_loss)
    print("gan_loss :", gan_loss)
```

I run this code on my `GTX2080` within a docker container `tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0-gpu-py3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Training a GAN implies some overhead that will not be executed on the GPU. In your case, obtaining `real_data_Y` and `fake_data_Y`, executing `get_random_data()` and computing the loss will result in GPU idle time.

You can try profiling your program with `python -mcProfile -o performance.prof xxx.py` and see if there are bottlenecks that can be improved, but 60 to 70% already seems not too bad.